# Simple jQuery hide not working in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I been searching around and trying different methods for quite a while and I can't seem to get the most basic implementation of what I want working.

I simply would like to manipulate a form on the homepage and the first thing I want to do is hide. I don't understand why my syntax is incorrect.

my form-

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div><%= f.label :first_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :last_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %></div>

      <div class="second_step"><%= f.label :profile_name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :profile_name %></div>

      <div class="second_step"><%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

      <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
    <% end %>

    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

The simple js in the assets/javascripts/file_name.js

```
 $('.second_step').hide();
```

My application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require justgage
//= require raphael.min
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require_tree .
```

=====

## UPDATE

console errors-

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL front.js:1
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:3000/assets/rails.j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error.

I had previously removed the .coffee extension on the file name and the first console error above wasn't recognizing the `#` in the default rails notes.

I got it working by adding back the coffee extension so as properly identify a `#` as a comment.

Everything is working below with the filename `front.js.coffee`
    # Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
    # All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
    # You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/

```
jQuery ->
     $('.second_step').hide();
```

Your answers helped in making sure my syntax was correct and that is was something outside the js. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

The `.` needs to be within the quotes:

```
 $('.second_step').hide();
```

Comment: And if it still not works then it is conflict with prototype, and to solve it you have to use `jQuery('.second_step').hide();`

Comment: The . outside the quotes was a typo. @Salil I tried this as well and it still did not work. see updated question for console errors.